# generar tabla cruzada con campo de subtotales

Tags: r

tengo la siguiente consulta, estoy tratando de generar una tabla cruzada de una base de datos, la base tiene un campo de condición inicial y condición final por periodos de tiempo, con el uso de table me genera el recuento de clientes, hay alguna forma que muestre los subtotales de la variable Monto en vez del recuento.  Adjunto el siguiente ejemplo.

```
    CODIGO <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11)
    MES <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
    CONDICION_FINAL <- c("A","A","A","B","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","B","B","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","A","A","B","B","A","B","B","C","B","C","D","E")
    CONDICION_INICIAL <- c("A","A","A","B","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","B","B","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","E","A","A","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
    MONTO <- c(500,450,430,430,100,100,100,100,250,250,250,250,180,180,400,400,400,400,300,300,300,300,800,800,800,800,400,350,300,300,200,180,180,180,900,800,800,800)
    dataFrame <- data.frame(CODIGO, MES, CONDICION_FINAL, CONDICION_INICIAL,MONTO)
```

Con esta función genero la tabla cruzada por periodo:

```
table(dataFrame$CONDICION_INICIAL, dataFrame$CONDICION_FINAL, dataFrame$MES)
```

Me da como cambia en números o conteo por mes, necesito el sub total de la variable Monto. Adicional, se puede generar automáticamente el promedio mensual.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes generar una salida similar a `table` pero con la suma de `MONTO` usando la función base `xtabs()`:

```
xtabs(MONTO ~ CONDICION_INICIAL + CONDICION_FINAL + MES, dataFrame)
```

La entrada es una formula que indica la variable a sumar y las variables de clasificación junto con el objeto al que pertenecen dichas variables.

Puedes combinar ambas salidas para calcular el promedio de forma muy natural:

```
t1 <- table(dataFrame$CONDICION_INICIAL, dataFrame$CONDICION_FINAL, dataFrame$MES)
t2 <- xtabs(MONTO ~ CONDICION_INICIAL + CONDICION_FINAL + MES, dataFrame)
t2 / t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa muy simple con `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
#library(tidyverse) #Alternativamente, si necesitas otras librerías de este paquete. 

dataFrame %>% 
  group_by(CONDICION_INICIAL, CONDICION_FINAL, MES) %>% 
  summarise(subtotal = sum(MONTO))
```

Que queda así:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   CONDICION_INICIAL, CONDICION_FINAL [8]
   CONDICION_INICIAL CONDICION_FINAL   MES subtotal
   <chr>             <chr>           <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A                 A                   1     1100
 2 A                 A                   2      800
 3 A                 A                   3      430
 4 A                 B                   2      180
 5 A                 B                   3      180
 6 A                 C                   4      180
 7 B                 B                   1     1380
 8 B                 B                   2      480
 9 B                 B                   4      430
10 B                 C                   2      800
11 B                 D                   3      800
12 B                 E                   4      800
13 E                 E                   1     1850
14 E                 E                   2     1850
15 E                 E                   3     1850
16 E                 E                   4     1850
```

Tiene tres diferencias con la solución con `xtabs`:

1. Regresa una data.frame en lugar de un objeto de la clase `table`, que internamente es un numérico con tres dimensiones. Cuál es mejor depende enteramente de lo que vayas a hacer después. Personalmente me entiendo más fácil con los data.frame, pero va en gustos.
2. Solo incluye las combinaciones observadas, es decir, por defecto no rellena con 0 las combinaciones de meses y condiciones sobre las que no tienes datos. De nuevo, cuál es mejor depende de lo que te interese hacer después. A veces es muy bueno ver explícitamente donde faltan datos, otras veces no aporta mucho.
3. Requiere cargar una librería. En general eso es peor.

También se puede adaptar para hacer promedios.

```
dataFrame %>% 
  group_by(CONDICION_INICIAL, CONDICION_FINAL, MES) %>% 
  summarise(subtotal = sum(MONTO), 
            conteo = n(), 
            promedio = subtotal/conteo)
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo.